# Log change sheet - the new value returns the original formula instead of the resulting output value

Tags: excel, vba

my code below logs all the changesof a cell into a new sheet. The old value and the old value are logged into this sheet. Here is the problem , if the new value comes from a formula, the cell returns the original value instead of logging the output value of that formula. Does anyone know how to fix this? thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Worksheets("Log - Ratio")
    Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName

    ' Uncomment the following line if you want to unprotect the sheet
    ' sh.Unprotect ""

    If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 6) = _
        Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "From", "To", "Sheet Name")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' to optimize the code (make it faster)
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("O32:CL32")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then
        TgValue = extractData(Target)
    Else
        TgValue = Array(Array(Target.Formula, Target.Address(0, 0))) ' put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
        boolOne = True
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' avoiding triggering the change event after UnDo
    Application.Undo
    RangeValues = extractData(Target) ' define the RangeValue
    putDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet ' put back the changed data
    If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Dim columnHeader As String, rowHeader As String
    For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
        If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
            ' Preserve the original formula
            sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).Value = _
                Array(Now, UN, RangeValues(r)(1), RangeValues(r)(0), TgValue(r)(0), Target.Parent.Name)
        End If
    Next r

    ' Uncomment the following line if you want to protect the sheet
    ' sh.Protect ""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub putDataBack(arr, sh As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Long, arrInt, El
    For Each El In arr
        sh.Range(El(1)).Value = El(0) ' Preserve the original formula
    Next
End Sub

Function extractData(Rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(Rng.Cells.count - 1)
    For Each a In Rng.Areas
        For i = 1 To a.Cells.count
            arr(count) = Array(a.Cells(i).Value, a.Cells(i).Address(0, 0)): count = count + 1
        Next
    Next
    extractData = arr
End Function
```

Comment: A recalculation of a formula will not trigger this event.

Comment: @ScottCraner. ohh indeed it makes sense! Would you happen to know how to modify this code to make it work when a formula is recalculated?